# How to have an encrypted partition/folder without any cleartext at all?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, luks, truecrypt

**How to have a partition/folder that does not show any unencrypted version of the files (i.e in cleartext)?**

To clarify, if I mount a folder called `folder` with `ecryptfs` and put a file called `file` in it

```
$ mkdir folder
$ mount -t ecryptfs folder folder
$ echo "word" > folder/file
```

I will have my file `file` in an unencrypted version until I umount the folder with the command `umount folder`.

What I want is in some sense only have the umounted version of my folder `folder`, without any cleartext at all as soon as the file is put in the encrypted folder or a "**hidden encrypted folder**".

Comment: I can do it by individual encryption but there may be a more elegant way. E.g `find | while read i; do gpg -e $i <key>; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ecrypted partition or directory encrypts the data *on the disk*. The data on the disk is *never* in cleartext. As long as the partition or directory is open or mounted you *see* the data in cleartext, but on the disk it remains encrypted. Essentially the full disk encryption or filesystem encryption software sits between the disk and the programs which read or write the files, and encrypts or decrypts the data on the fly -- that's why such software is sometimes called OTFE, On The Fly Encryption. Since the data appears in cleartext while the partition or directory is mounted, such systems are said to protect *data at rest*.

In your example, the file `folder/file` is encrypted as soon as you write the first character into it. It appears in cleartext because the directory `folder` is mounted; while it is mounted, the eCryptfs software translates automatically between the ciphertext on the disk and the cleartext presented to the programs. You are right that this is not the only way that an encrypted partition or subtree can  possibly work, but as far as I know all encrypted filesystems work in this way.

If you want to encrypt one or more files without leaving any plaintext visible and maintaining access to the ciphertext then you cannot use software which appears as a filesystem; you must use software which encrypts or decrypts files. [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) is free and widely used.